# FlashVars works locally but not live server

Tags: flash, server, actionscript, flashvars

I did some code for making a flash audio player .. This player takes the sound source by its FlashVars param. Its working locally fine .. But when it is in server only shows swf file but does dot play sound as expected. Why this happens. My actionscript code is bellow..

```
var keyStr:String;
var valueStr:String;
var paramObj:Object = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters;   //set the paramObj variable to the parameters property of the LoaderInfo object
for (keyStr in paramObj) 
{
    valueStr = String(paramObj[keyStr]);
    var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(valueStr); 

}

    sound_icon.visible =  true
sound_icon.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playSound);
var s:Sound = new Sound(req); 
gotoAndStop("f2");//firstly  animated sound icon is stopped at the beginning position

function playSound(e:MouseEvent):void{
    sound_icon.visible =  false; //hide sound icon
    gotoAndPlay("f2");           //play animated sound icon from beginning

var mySoundChannel:SoundChannel = s.play(); //reference for getting complete event

mySoundChannel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, songFinished);
function songFinished(ev:Event):void
{
   sound_icon.visible =  true;
   gotoAndStop("f2");
}
```

}

and php code is below

```
    <div id="flashContent">

        <?php


        $swfSourcePath = "soundtest.swf";
        $soundSourcePath = "4.mp3"; 

        ?>

        <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="40" height="40" id="soundtest" align="middle">
            <param name="movie" value="<?php echo $swfSourcePath;?>" />
                <param name=FlashVars value="myVariable=<?php echo $soundSourcePath;?>" />

            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="soundtest.swf" width="40" height="40">
                <param name="movie" value="<?php echo $swfSourcePath;?>" />
                    <param name=FlashVars value="myVariable=<?php echo  $soundSourcePath;?>" />

            <!--<![endif]-->
                <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
                    <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                </a>
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            </object>
            <!--<![endif]-->
        </object>
    </div>
```

Comment: Is your 4.mp3 in the same directory as your PHP page? Are you sure the MP3 file is on the server? You could create a textfield on the stage and fill it with the "valueStr" variable to check if the flashvars are passed correctly and the "s.url" variable to check if the set sound path is correct

Answer (score 1):

There are some options:

- If you use Flash Professional / Animate open File - Publish Settings - Local playback security, set it to Access Network only.
- Try to use "flashvars" instead of FlashVars
- Try to set source as "soundtest.swf?myVariable=4.mp3"